# extract string from line in a file

Tags: python, file

I have two files one of them contains lines like

```
 0    rho is 2313.22
 1    rho is 6456.01
 .....
 18811 rho is 2154.78
 18812 rho is 2279.565
 18813 rho is 1813.690
 18814 rho is 346.20664
```

the second file contains some of the numbers not arranged in a sequential manner like

```
18812
758
2623
12569
1392
```

i need to extract its rho values from file1. i tried to compare between two files and if it found numbers exist it should return the rho values but couldn't do this part

```
with open('file1', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('results.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: So, in your given example, what exactly is the desired result? It doesn't seem like *any* of the numbers match anything else.

Comment: If file1 really is sequentially (0, N-1), then you just need to extract the last token from each, and index into it using the indices from file2. If they're not sequential, you need to create a mapping from point to rho. Either of these will work, but please show us what you've tried.

Comment: the file1 contains 30.000 value i gave example for my problem but illustrate that in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

#load file1 as csv, split on whitespace, name columns and drop redundant text columns
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='\s+', names=['id', 0, 1, 'value']).drop(columns=[0, 1])

#load file2 as csv, name column
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', names=['id'])

#merge dataframes, keep only values that exist in df2 and write output to csv file
df2.merge(df1, on='id').to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a more "data engineering" approach, and open the 2 files as csv with pandas, then do a merge.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the first file as a csv file, considering "rho is" as the separator 
rho_map = pd.read_csv('file1', sep="rho is", 
                     header=None, names=['id', 'rho',])

# read the second file
data = pd.read_csv('file2', names=['id'])

# Then merge
results = data.merge(rho_map, on='id')
```

With a subset from your test data, you could have file1 with:

```
 18811 rho is 2154.78
 18812 rho is 2279.565
 18813 rho is 1813.690
 18814 rho is 346.20664
```

and file2 with

```
18812
758
2623
12569
1392
```

This will give as result :

```
    id  rho
0   18812   2279.565
```